# Pythonにおける変数の値参照について質問です

Tags: python, アルゴリズム, データ構造

LeetCodeのアルゴリズム第83問について質問です。

https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list/

以下問題文と入力，出力例です。

> Given the head of a sorted linked list, delete all duplicates such that each element appears only once. Return the linked list sorted as well.
>
> 例1
>
> ```
> Input: head = [1,1,2]
> Output: [1,2]
> ```
>
> 例2
>
> ```
> Input: head = [1,1,2,3,3]
> Output: [1,2,3]
> ```

下記のコードで正解することはできたのですが，なぜheadの値が更新されるのかわからないです。
whileループ中にheadの値を出力すると関数deleteDuplicatesが呼び出された直後の値（重複を許した単方向リスト）が出力されますが，whileループを抜けると重複のない単方向リストに変化しています。
どのような挙動によってこのようなことが起こっているのでしょうか。

```py
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next

class Solution:
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        current_node = head
        prev_node = None
        nums = set()
        while current_node:
            if current_node.val not in nums:
                nums.add(current_node.val)
                next_node = current_node.next
                prev_node = current_node
                current_node = next_node
                
            elif current_node.val in nums:
                next_node = current_node.next
                prev_node.next = next_node
                current_node = next_node

        return head
```

Comment: 此処の質問記事に記述したソースコードだけで完結する形にした方が良いと思われます。更には紹介された先のページを見ても、登録していない人にはどうやれば質問の内容を再現できるのか直ぐには分からなそうです。これらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問内容やソースコードを変更してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) あるいはこんなFAQなどを探すと類似の現象があるかもしれませんね。[プログラミング FAQ](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/faq/programming.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SolutionクラスのdeleteDuplicatesメソッドで最初に実行されるのは`current_node = head`です。
このときcurrent_nodeにはheadの参照が代入されます。

whileループでcurrent_nodeを操作していますが、これはheadを操作しているのと同じです。

`current_node = head`を`head_save = head`に書き換え、
whileループの中のcurrent_nodeをすべてheadに書き換え、
headsaveの値でreturnしてもロジックは変わりません。

```py
class Solution:
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head):
        head_save = head
        prev_node = None
        nums = set()
        while head:
            if head.val not in nums:
                nums.add(head.val)
                next_node = head.next
                prev_node = head
                head = next_node

            elif head.val in nums:
                next_node = head.next
                prev_node.next = next_node
                head = next_node

        return head_save
```

このコードは引数headを書き換えていますが、引数の書き換えを勧めている意図はありません。あくまでも説明用のコードです。